# ActiveRecord Group and Count - Where Does count_id Come From?

Tags: activerecord

I have `Order` and `Item` models joined by `OrderItem`:

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item
```

This query finds the IDs of the most popular items:

```
OrderItem.group(:item_id).order("count_id DESC").count("id").first(10).map(&:first)
```

This works, but what is `count_id`?  Why does this work?  What is going on here behind the scenes with `order("count_id...`?

Answer (score 0):

`count_id` is an alias that Rails gives to the SQL aggregate function `COUNT("order_items"."id")`.

`OrderItem.group(:item_id).count(:id)` counts the number of rows for each individual item:

```
SELECT COUNT("order_items"."id") AS count_id, item_id AS item_id FROM "order_items"  GROUP BY item_id
```

The magic behind the `count_id` part is in [`ActiveRecord::Calculations`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb).  The alias is determined here:

```
aggregate_alias = column_alias_for([operation, column_name].join(' '))
```

And the method comments for `column_alias_for` list show this example:

```
#   column_alias_for("count", "id")              # => "count_id"
```

After that, `order` lists the Item occurrences from largest to smallest.  The return value will be a hash where the keys are Item IDs and the values are the count of occurrences.

`first` grabs the 10 items with the most occurrences, and `map` pulls out the `item_id` values.