# Getting Activerecord count of a group (Rails 4.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by, count, rails-activerecord

I am trying to process a set of data organized by category; the ActiveRecord query below is what I've been using to lay out the table (category titles, then product info (for performance reasons it's been done in the view, with as much logic put to the model as possible.)

I have been trying to report two things:

1. Loop through an ordered list of the most used categories by number of products; and
2. Report the number of products in those categories.

I've tried implementing what I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683567/activerecord-group-and-count-where-does-count-id-come-from) but had difficulties getting `count_id` accepted.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %> 
  <p><%= category.name %>;</p>
  <% category.products.includes(:rfid_tags).joins(:rfid_tags).order(name: :asc).limit(10).each do |product| %>
    <p><%= product.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Category model (exported this bit of the logic IRL to keep it short):

```
def warehouse_product_grouping
  self.products.includes(:rfid_tags).joins(:rfid_tags)
end  


Models:

#Warehouse.rb

has_many :tags, as: :location
has_many :products, through: :tags

#rfid_tag.rb

belongs_to product #

  #polymorphic
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :location, polymorphic: true

#Product.rb

  has_one :primary_category_assignment

  has_many :rfid_tags, as: :trackable
```

Each product is assigned to a category - associations are warehouses > tags > products > category_assignment > category.

```
#CategoryAssignment.rb #this is a join table
  belongs_to :product, required: true
  belongs_to :category, required: true

#Category.rb
  has_many :products, through: :category_assignment
```

Comment: Please show your models: `Category` and `Product`

Comment: "Report the number of products" can be done simply by `category.products.count`. To avoid N + 1 query problem I suggest to include products when working with categories: `<% @categories.includes(:products).each do |category| %>`

Comment: right, that's why I have the tags set up that way - I can access everything about the products themselves, but the way it's currently grouped makes it fail when I try to grab a count. Models are added.

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov This does work though- Add this as an answer and I'll vote it in.

Comment: Sure thing. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Report the number of products" can be done simply by `category.products.count`. To avoid N + 1 query problem I suggest to include products when working with categories: `<% @categories.includes(:products).each do |category| %>`